# Is there a TTL or CMOS shift register chip which has an output pin telling you when it has shifted out all (8) bits?

Tags: counter, shift-register, ripple-counter

Quick question, I'm going through 74x and CD4x chips to see if there is a parallel load serial out (left) shift register which would have the convenience of telling you when it is done shifting everything out? I am trying to avoid running an 3 bit counter on the side to know when all is shifted out.

Comment: You mean a FIFO chip. but small is 4-bit x 16-word FIFO register

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, I mean an 8-bit parallel in serial out shift register.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the chip manufacturers don't assume everyone wants to shift exactly 8 bits. For example, it's common to daisy-chain shift registers together to make a long shift register and the total number of bits may not be a multiple of 8.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that's what I figured. Just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

If the chip has a clear pin you can do the following.

1. Toggle the clear pin to clear the register (you could also do this by shifting in at least 8 zeroes instead).
2. Shift in a '1'
3. Shift in the 8 data bits.

When the '1' comes out the other end you will know you shifted all 8 data bits.

Comment: That's cool for shift in, but not out. Good idea though.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this goal but not with just one shift register chip. What you want to do is to have two of the same shift register packages that you would run in parallel. One shift register operated with your parallel loaded data and then shifts out when clocked with the shift clock. The other parallel operated shift register will have all its parallel load input data lines connected to GND.

The serial shift in pin is pulled up to the VCC/VDD. The parallel load and shift clock connections of the two parallel shift registers are tied together and driven from the same source signal. The serial shift output from the second shift register will be the indication that shifting is complete when it goes high.

If you would like to have the shift complete come at the same time that the last bit shows up then instead of connecting all the second registers parallel load inputs to GND you would connect the last input also to the VCC/VDD.